# XML::Twig : how to specify a twig_handler for a <_tag> which starts with an underscore?

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-twig

I have an XML file whose root element tag is `<__>` (two underscores).  When, however, that tag name is used in the twig_handlers list XML::Twig->new dies with the error message:

```
unrecognized expression in handler: '__'
```

Actually, ANY tag starting with an underscore produces this error except for Twig's special tags `_all_` and `_default_`, either of which I can use to process the file at the expense of throwing away all the handler callbacks except the last.

The invocation which fails is:

```
XML::Twig->new (twig_handlers => { '__' => \&show })
```

I imagine there's an XML::Twig Xpath expression which can be used here but the CPAN documentaton is pretty vague about their syntax.  I also now wonder what I'd have to do to get at an element `<_all_>` :)

If anyone has a suggestion it would be much appreciated.

The problem only occurs when the twig is created since once processing has started (using the callback expression `_all_`), `<__>` elements at any level in the input are processed normally.

If anyone wants to play with the problem, here's the program I was using to try finding a solution.  Set $xpath to the expression you want to test.

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $xpath = '_all_';    # <---- fails if one puts '__' here

my $xml = <<EOS;        # <---- here's the XML data to process
<__>
   <AA>first</AA>
   <__>second</__>
</__>
EOS

sub show {
    print "handler called for element ", $_->gi, ", whose children are\n";
    my @children = $_->children;
    for my $elt (@children) {
        print "\t", $elt->gi, " holds \"", $elt->text, "\"\n";
    }
    1;
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new (twig_handlers => { $xpath => \&show });
$twig->parse ($xml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of XML::Twig are you using? This is a bug that was fixed in version 3.38.

From the Changes file:

```
version 3.38
date: 2011-02-27
# minor maintenance release
fixed: RT 65865: _ should be allowed at the start on an XML name
       https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=65865
       reported by Steve Prokopowich
```

And indeed when I use '__' as the value for `$xpath` the code runs without errors, and gives the correct output.

Comment: Thank you **very** much.  My current version of XML::Twig is 3.34.  I'll see if I can get the update tomorrow and will confirm that it fixes the problem as soon as I can.  (The next available "stable" version on Debian seems to be 3.39.)

Comment: Hello Mirod, have just installed version 3.39 and, as advertised, the problem's gone.  Thanks again for your patience and help :)